# MySQL get top 3 rows in for each group of results

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

This is a *similar* question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results), but differs slightly.

In the simplest way possible, I have a table that comprises of the following data:

```
| id | post_id |           time_stamp |
|----|---------|----------------------|
|  1 |       1 | 2022-05-07T03:07:18Z |
|  2 |       1 | 2022-05-07T03:07:19Z |
|  3 |       1 | 2022-05-07T03:07:20Z |
|  4 |       1 | 2022-05-07T03:07:21Z |
|  5 |       2 | 2022-05-07T03:07:18Z |
|  6 |       2 | 2022-05-07T03:07:19Z |
|  7 |       2 | 2022-05-07T03:07:20Z |
|  8 |       2 | 2022-05-07T03:07:21Z |
|  9 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:02Z |
| 10 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:03Z |
| 11 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:04Z |
| 12 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:05Z |
| 13 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:06Z |
| 14 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:07Z |
| 15 |       4 | 2022-05-07T03:07:02Z |
| 16 |       4 | 2022-05-07T03:07:03Z |
| 17 |       4 | 2022-05-07T03:07:04Z |
| 18 |       4 | 2022-05-07T03:07:05Z |
| 19 |       5 | 2022-05-07T03:07:06Z |
| 20 |       5 | 2022-05-07T03:07:07Z |
```

Essentially, I'd like to get the three most recent results from each `post_id`, and specifically for **only a few** `post_id`'s.
Currently I'm using the following query (inspired from the question linked at the top):

```sql
SELECT r.*
FROM post_reply r
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM post_reply b
  WHERE b.post_id = r.post_id AND b.time_stamp >= r.time_stamp
) <= 3
and r.post_id in (1, 2, 3)
ORDER BY r.post_id ASC, r.time_stamp DESC;
```

Which returns the following result:

```
| id | post_id |           time_stamp |
|----|---------|----------------------|
|  4 |       1 | 2022-05-07T03:07:21Z |
|  3 |       1 | 2022-05-07T03:07:20Z |
|  2 |       1 | 2022-05-07T03:07:19Z |
|  8 |       2 | 2022-05-07T03:07:21Z |
|  7 |       2 | 2022-05-07T03:07:20Z |
|  6 |       2 | 2022-05-07T03:07:19Z |
| 14 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:07Z |
| 13 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:06Z |
| 12 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:05Z |
```

This works just fine, until you begin to have some entries with **duplicate** timestamps.

For the next dataset, we'll use some duplicate values for the timestamps:

```
| id | post_id |           time_stamp |
|----|---------|----------------------|
|  1 |       1 | 2022-05-07T03:07:18Z |
|  2 |       1 | 2022-05-07T03:07:18Z |
|  3 |       1 | 2022-05-07T03:07:18Z |
|  4 |       1 | 2022-05-07T03:07:18Z |
|  5 |       2 | 2022-05-07T03:07:18Z |
|  6 |       2 | 2022-05-07T03:07:18Z |
|  7 |       2 | 2022-05-07T03:07:18Z |
|  8 |       2 | 2022-05-07T03:07:19Z |
|  9 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:19Z |
| 10 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:03Z |
| 11 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:04Z |
| 12 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:05Z |
| 13 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:06Z |
| 14 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:07Z |
| 15 |       4 | 2022-05-07T03:07:02Z |
| 16 |       4 | 2022-05-07T03:07:03Z |
| 17 |       4 | 2022-05-07T03:07:04Z |
| 18 |       4 | 2022-05-07T03:07:05Z |
| 19 |       5 | 2022-05-07T03:07:06Z |
| 20 |       5 | 2022-05-07T03:07:07Z |
```

Which returns much less data:

```
| id | post_id |           time_stamp |
|----|---------|----------------------|
|  8 |       2 | 2022-05-07T03:07:19Z |
|  9 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:19Z |
| 14 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:07Z |
| 13 |       3 | 2022-05-07T03:07:06Z |
```

Previously, I tried a different approach to the query by using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in the subquery:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM post_reply r
WHERE r.id IN (
  SELECT pr.id
  FROM post_reply pr
  WHERE pr.id = p.id
  ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
  LIMIT 3
)
AND pr.id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

However, I'm met with **This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'**

I'm SOL and out of ideas and could definitely use some help understanding how I can reliably achieve what I'd like to do.

[Here's an SQLFiddle I've been using to work on the query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76cb83)

Comment: could help you some kind of CTE or rank?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: Never heard of CTE o.O - Could you provide an example please?

Comment: You did not explain what you want when there are duplicate dates. Post your expected results. Also, what is your version of MySql?

Comment: @SteppingHat there is plenty of examples here and in web, and I can't do it in a comment, or btw could not be an answer in S.O. so I suggest you search about CTE that I think is what you need instead a subquery. Search about the link that I give you also

Comment: I linked this question to a past question I answered, which gives three different solutions to this general type of query. Included in that answer is an example of using a CTE with window functions. Since you tagged your question MariaDB, you should note that [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/) are supported in MariaDB 10.2.0 and later, and [CTE syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/common-table-expressions/) is supported in MariaDB 10.2.1 and later.